# I am getting error when declaring "byteA" as var. How to fix it?

Tags: c#

Getting error when declaring "byteA" as var. I am trying to print an invoice using bytes array.

```
    private void btn_close_bill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrinterUtility.EscPosEpsonCommands.EscPosEpson obj = new PrinterUtility.EscPosEpsonCommands.EscPosEpson();
        var byteA;
        byteA = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(byteA, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Name\n"));
        byteA = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(byteA, obj.CharSize.DoubleWidth4());
        byteA = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(byteA, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Address\n"));
        byteA = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(byteA, obj.CharSize.DoubleWidth2());
        byteA = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(byteA, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("TP Number\n"));
        byteA = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(byteA, obj.CharSize.DoubleWidth2());
        PrinterUtility.PrintExtensions.Print(byteA, Foodcity_Management_System.Properties.Settings.Default.PrinterPath);

   }
```

Comment: `var` can be used only when you assign a value. Otherwise the compiler can not determine the type that should be used. Therefore your declaration `var byteA;` is illegal, but you can do: `var byteA = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(byteA, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Name\n"));` Unfprtunatelly this will be ilegal, because you use node defined value of `byteA` in the call.

Comment: read docs on `var (C# keyword)`. the error is because C# is a typed language, you need to declare the type when you declare a variable, or the compiler needs to be able to deduce the type from the code like `var a = 5`.

Comment: @Julo it's not recommended to post answers as comments, please post an answer. I'm sure it's correct

Comment: @opewix I had already many downvotes and negative comments for such a simple and correct answers, that I do not like to post such a answer without correct and full research. Moreover, this question has another problem. *(See edit of my first comment.)*

Answer (score 5):

When declaring a variable using the `var` keyword, you must set it's value in the same code line in such a way that the compiler can infer it's type.

If you don't assign a typed value to it when declaring it (an anonymous type also counts as a type) the compiler can't know what type it is and therefor will not compile the code.

This is also why you can't do `var x = null;` (but you can do `var y = (string)null;`).

You can probably get your code to work with `var byteA = new byte[];` (you said you needed a byte array) - or at least to compile (I don't know what the `AddBytes` function does so you might need a different type, perhaps an `IList<type>`?)

Comment: A quick google search indicates that this function takes a byte array so this answer is probably correct. `var byteA = new byte[0];`

Answer (score 0):

When using the keyword var you need to give it an initial value so the compiler knows what type it is eg : instead of saying int number; we can use var number = 0. these 2 variables are integers.

Comment: Simply assigning it the value 0 will not make it type `byte`. You could do `var byteA = (byte)0;` but then you might as well just explicitly declare the type in the first place.